# Summation involving totient function: $\sum_{d\mid n} \varphi(d)=n$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, summation, totient-function

Prove that:$$\sum_{d\mid n} \varphi(d)=n$$

Where $\varphi(n)$ denotes the number of positive integers $m$ less than or equal to $n$ such that $\gcd(m,n)=1$

I am lost here, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you know that $\phi$ is multiplicative, and you know that this kind of sum of a multiplicative function is multiplicative, all you have to do is prove it in the case $n$ is prime.

Comment: @GerryMyerson In case $n$ is prime, the sum is $\varphi(1)+\varphi(n)$ right?

Comment: Yes --- do you know what $\phi(1)$ is? what $\phi(n)$ is, if $n$ is prime?

Comment: @GerryMyerson oooh. never mind. stupid question. thanks a lot.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Do you mean prime or prime power?

Comment: I am somewhat surprised that this was not asked and answered on this site before. At least I was not able to find anything apart from [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/713806/on-proving-n-sum-d-mid-n-varphid), which is about OP's attempt to prove this.

Comment: @MartinSleziak oh good. it is OK to post my own answer right? I came up with a proof based on counting arguments, because I don't fully comprehend Gerry's point of the summation being multiplicative.

Comment: AFAIK answering your own questions is encouraged, you will probably be able to find some relevant discussions on meta, according to [this blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) it is even encouraged.

Comment: @MartinSleziak oh that's very encouraging. :D

Comment: Clearly I did not search properly. It seems that this question has duplicates: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/194705/is-there-a-direct-elementary-proof-of-n-sum-kn-phik and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/504063/show-sum-limits-dn-phid-n

Comment: @MartinSleziak thanks for pointing out.

Comment: @Erick, oops, prime power.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is my proof, based on counting arguments.

Consider the fractions $$\frac1{n},\frac{2}{n},\frac{3}{n},\cdots,\frac{n}{n}$$

Obviously there are $n$ such fractions.

Now consider these fractions, simplified to their lowest terms.

In each of these fractions, the denominator has to be a divisor of $n$. The number of fractions, in which the denominator is *still*  equal to $n$, is the number of fractions whose numerator was originally relatively prime to $n$, i.e, $\varphi(n)$.

Similarly, for any given $d$, where $d$ is a divisor of $n$, there will be $\varphi(d)$ such fractions where the denominator is equal to $d$. Adding all these $\varphi(d)$ thus returns the total number of fractions, $n$.

So we arrive at the equality,

$$\sum_{d\mid n}\varphi(d)=n$$

Comment: The last parraph's argument isn't clear to me: there could possibly be fractions for which $\;\frac kd=\frac{k'}{d'}\;$ , for two different divisors $\;d,d'\;$ of $\;n\;$ , and thus apparently your method would count these ones twice...

Comment: @DonAntonio *lowest* terms

Comment: What sticks in my craw about this argument is that fractions are really *inessential* to the problem; they get brought in only because they come with a built-in, widely recognized "simplified to lowest terms" operation.  IOW, fractions show up in this theorem only as, basically, a cute hack, and IMO they obscure what's *really* happening in the theorem, namely that (1) *every* $m \in \def\nset{\{1,\dots,n\}}\nset$ can be written *uniquely* as the product $du$ where $d\mid n$ and $\gcd(u, n/d) = 1$, and (2) every such product $du$ belongs to $\nset$. $\;\;\dots$

Comment: @kjo i never said my solution was *elegant* it just worked for me.

Comment: $\dots\;\;$ These means that $\nset$ can be partitioned according to the $d$ factor of these products, and the size of each partition is $\varphi(n/d)$.  But don't get me wrong: such proofs are OK, as quick ways to convince oneself that something is true, but one needs to go beyond them to get at the essence of why something is true.

Comment: @Sabyasachi: sorry, I had not finished with my comment.  Also, on the contrary, I think your proof is *extremely* elegant.  I'm making the case for *inelegance* here.

Comment: @kjo really? thank you then.

Comment: FWIW I think this proof is very elegant.

Answer (score 5):

Consider the cyclic group $C_n$. Then, for every $g\in C_n$, $o(g)$ divides $|C_n|=n$. Moreover, for any $d|C_n$, $\exists g\in C_n:o(g)=d$. Thereofore, if $A_k$ is the set of all the elements of $C_n$ with order $k$, $A_k \neq \emptyset \Longleftrightarrow k | n$. Therefore, $\{A_k : k | n\}$ is a partition of $C_n$. So:

$$|C_n|= n = \displaystyle{\sum _{g \in C_n}} 1 = \displaystyle{\sum _{d|n} |A_d|} = \displaystyle{\sum _{d|n} \varphi(d)}$$

Since the number of elements of order $d$ in $C_n$ is $\varphi(d)$.

Comment: Why is $|A_d| = \varphi(d)$?