# Prove that φ(n) + d(n) ≤ n + 1

Tags: elementary-number-theory, totient-function, divisor-counting-function

Prove that φ(n) + d(n) ≤ n + 1.

d(n) is the number of positive divisors of n.

φ(n) is the Euler's Totient Function.

Attempt：

- For a prime number n, φ(n) = n - 1 (all numbers less than n are relatively prime to n except for 1) and d(n) = 2 (1 and n), so φ(n) + d(n) = n - 1 + 2 = n + 1, which satisfies the inequality.
- For a composite number n, φ(n) is less than $n - \sqrt{n}$ and d(n) is less than $2\sqrt{n}$.

Comment: Hint. Every divisor $d>1$ of $n$ is not relatively prime to $n$.

Comment: Please use MathJax. Here is a
[tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: FYI, I found the duplicate using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Cvarphi(n)%2Bd(n)%5Cle%20n%2B1%24&p=1). Also, as indicated in Wikipedia's [Divisor function's Definitions section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_function#Definition), an alternate notation for $d(n)$ is $\tau(n)$. Finally, welcome to Math SE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have

$$n = \sum_{d\mid n} \varphi(d)\,,$$

so

$$\varphi(n) + d(n) = n - \sum_{\substack{d\mid n \\ d < n}} \varphi(d) + \sum_{d \mid n} 1 = (n+1) - \sum_{\substack{d \mid n \\ 1 < d < n}}\bigl(\varphi(d) - 1\bigr)\,.$$

This is at most $n+1$.

Comment: for future reader: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/715247/summation-involving-totient-function-sum-d-mid-n-varphid-n